# JavaScript вернуть элемент с родителями дерева

Tags: javascript, дерево

Я хочу сделать функцию, которая принимает массив `id` и возвращает фильтры на основе дерева, с родителями. К примеру, если в функцию передам `[2, 6]`, то хочу получить(на основе массива `filtersWithId`, который я объявил в самом низу сниппета, он выводится в консоль):

```json
[
    {
      item: 'Сегмент',
      type: 'checkbox',
      id: 1,
      children: [
        { item: 'Малый бизнес',  type: 'checkbox', id: 2 }
      ]
    },
    {
      item: 'Продукт или канал',
      type: 'checkbox',
      id: 4,
      children: [
        {
          item: 'РКО',
          type: 'checkbox'
          id: 5,
          children: [
            { item: 'Ведение счёта', type: 'checkbox', id: 6 },
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
]
```

Как видно по этому массиву - из массива children нужно удалять те элементы, id которых не переданно

Я в своём коде использовал функцию preOrder, чтобы проходиться по каждой ветке, когда проставлял каждому объекту id.
Я пытаюсь думать как это сделать, но пока ничего не приходит в голову.

```js
function putIdFilters(filters_) {

  const filters = filters_.slice();
  const map = new Map();

  let num = 0;
  preOrder(filters);

  function preOrder(node) {
    if (node == null) {
      return;
    }

    if (node.length === 1) {
      node[0].id = ++num;
      map.set(node[0].id, node[0]);
      return;
    }

    node.forEach(item => {
      item.id = ++num;
      map.set(item.id, item);
      preOrder(item.children);
    });
  }

  return {
    arr: filters,
    map: map
  };

}

const filters = [{
    item: 'Сегмент',
    type: 'checkbox',
    children: [{
        item: 'Малый бизнес',
        type: 'checkbox'
      },
      {
        item: 'Средний бизнес',
        type: 'checkbox'
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    item: 'Продукт или канал',
    type: 'checkbox',
    children: [{
        item: 'РКО',
        children: [{
            item: 'Ведение счёта',
            type: 'checkbox'
          },
          {
            item: 'Открытие счёта',
            type: 'checkbox'
          },
          {
            item: 'Закрытие счёта',
            type: 'checkbox'
          },
          {
            item: 'Платежи и переводы',
            type: 'checkbox'
          },
          {
            item: 'Кассовые операции',
            type: 'checkbox'
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        item: 'Кредиты и гарантии',
        type: 'checkbox',
        children: [{
            item: 'Кредиты в целом',
            type: 'checkbox'
          },
          {
            item: 'Экспресс кредитование',
            type: 'checkbox'
          },
          {
            item: 'Овердрафт',
            type: 'checkbox'
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        item: 'Бизнес-портал',
        type: 'checkbox'
      },
      {
        item: 'Офисы',
        type: 'checkbox'
      },
      {
        item: 'Банкоматы',
        type: 'checkbox'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    item: 'Тематика',
    type: 'checkbox',
    children: [{
        item: 'Медленное / несвоевременное обслуживание',
        type: 'checkbox'
      },
      {
        item: 'Невыгодные условия / тарифы',
        type: 'checkbox'
      },
      {
        item: 'Проблемы с информированием',
        type: 'checkbox'
      },
      {
        item: 'Блокировки / ограничения',
        type: 'checkbox'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    item: 'Источник',
    type: 'checkbox',
    children: [{
        item: 'Опросы',
        type: 'checkbox'
      },
      {
        item: 'Жалобы и претензии',
        type: 'checkbox'
      },
      {
        item: 'Блокировки / ограничения',
        type: 'checkbox'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    item: 'Отзывы',
    type: 'checkbox',
    children: [{
        item: 'Негативные',
        type: 'checkbox'
      },
      {
        item: 'Оценка',
        type: 'slider',
        slider: {
          from: 0,
          to: 10
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    item: 'Не отзывы',
    type: 'checkbox',
    children: [{
        item: 'Негативные',
        type: 'checkbox'
      },
      {
        item: 'Оценка по не отзывам',
        type: 'slider',
        slider: {
          from: 0,
          to: 14
        }
      }
    ]
  }
];

const filtersWithId = putIdFilters(filters).arr;
console.log(filtersWithId);
```

Comment: Я ничего не понял.

Comment: @Igor поправил, указал, что хочу получить дерево на основе массива

Comment: Из условия не очень понял что требуется, поправьте если не прав, на входе имеем дерево с элементами без ID нужна функция которая проставит ID всем элементам дерева?

Comment: Хотя судя по заголовку список уже имеет ID, и нужна функция которая принимает дерево и список ID и возвращает списов родительских элементов которые содержат элементы с входящими ID?

Comment: Упростите вопрос: по типу есть массив `[{name:"first", id: "first_id"},{name:"second",id: "second_id"}...]` хочу чтобы при вводе в функцию массив function([2, 3]) получалось то то. Я с деревьями и их родителями не совсем понял что должно в итоге то получится

Comment: @Greg-- я привёл пример, что при вызове функции, которой мы дадим на вход массив [2, 6] выдаст какой результат

Comment: @mego4iter можно сказать так

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно так, если вы не хотите мутировать исходный массив

```js
const filters = [{
item: 'Сегмент',
type: 'checkbox',
children: [{
    item: 'Малый бизнес',
    type: 'checkbox'
  },
  {
    item: 'Средний бизнес',
    type: 'checkbox'
  },
]
  },
  {
item: 'Продукт или канал',
type: 'checkbox',
children: [{
    item: 'РКО',
    children: [{
        item: 'Ведение счёта',
        type: 'checkbox'
      },
      {
        item: 'Открытие счёта',
        type: 'checkbox'
      },
      {
        item: 'Закрытие счёта',
        type: 'checkbox'
      },
      {
        item: 'Платежи и переводы',
        type: 'checkbox'
      },
      {
        item: 'Кассовые операции',
        type: 'checkbox'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    item: 'Кредиты и гарантии',
    type: 'checkbox',
    children: [{
        item: 'Кредиты в целом',
        type: 'checkbox'
      },
      {
        item: 'Экспресс кредитование',
        type: 'checkbox'
      },
      {
        item: 'Овердрафт',
        type: 'checkbox'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    item: 'Бизнес-портал',
    type: 'checkbox'
  },
  {
    item: 'Офисы',
    type: 'checkbox'
  },
  {
    item: 'Банкоматы',
    type: 'checkbox'
  }
]
  },
  {
item: 'Тематика',
type: 'checkbox',
children: [{
    item: 'Медленное / несвоевременное обслуживание',
    type: 'checkbox'
  },
  {
    item: 'Невыгодные условия / тарифы',
    type: 'checkbox'
  },
  {
    item: 'Проблемы с информированием',
    type: 'checkbox'
  },
  {
    item: 'Блокировки / ограничения',
    type: 'checkbox'
  }
]
  },
  {
item: 'Источник',
type: 'checkbox',
children: [{
    item: 'Опросы',
    type: 'checkbox'
  },
  {
    item: 'Жалобы и претензии',
    type: 'checkbox'
  },
  {
    item: 'Блокировки / ограничения',
    type: 'checkbox'
  }
]
  },
  {
item: 'Отзывы',
type: 'checkbox',
children: [{
    item: 'Негативные',
    type: 'checkbox'
  },
  {
    item: 'Оценка',
    type: 'slider',
    slider: {
      from: 0,
      to: 10
    }
  }
]
  },
  {
item: 'Не отзывы',
type: 'checkbox',
children: [{
    item: 'Негативные',
    type: 'checkbox'
  },
  {
    item: 'Оценка по не отзывам',
    type: 'slider',
    slider: {
      from: 0,
      to: 14
    }
  }
]
  }
];

const filteringTree = getFilteringTree(filters,[29, 32, 26]);

console.log(filteringTree);
function getFilteringTree(data,filterArr){
  const temp = {};
  let num = 0;
  let parent = null;
  let parentsList = [];
  preOrder(data);

  function preOrder(node) {
if (!node) {return;}
else{
  node.map(item => {
  ++num;
  temp[num]={parent, id:num, node:item};
  parentsList.push(parent);
  parent = temp[num];
  preOrder(item.children);
  if(parentsList.length>0) parent = parentsList.pop();
  else parent=null;
});
}
  }
  return filterArr.reduce((acc,index)=>{
if(temp[index]){
  acc.push(cloneBranch(temp[index]));
}
return acc;
  },[]);
  
  function cloneBranch(item){
let _item = item;
let result = {..._item.node,id:_item.id}
delete result.children;
while(_item.parent){
  result = {..._item.parent.node,id:_item.parent.id,children:[result]}
  _item = _item.parent;
}
return result;
  }
}
```

Comment: у вас на `[2,6]` работает как раз так, как я хотел! Но на `[29, 32, 26]` работает не так. Не получается исходный родитель.

Comment: поправил, надо было ветку предков на каждом узле сохранять

Answer (score 1):

Если вас правильно понял, список рутовых элементов можно получить с помощью reduce и рекурсии.

```js
const filters = [{
    item: 'Сегмент',
    type: 'checkbox',
    id: 1,
    children: [
      {
        item: 'Малый бизнес',
        type: 'checkbox',
        id: 2,
      },
      {
        item: 'Средний бизнес',
        type: 'checkbox',
        id: 3,
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    item: 'Продукт или канал',
    type: 'checkbox',
    id: 4,
    children: [
      {
        item: 'РКО',
        id: 5,
        children: [
          {
            item: 'Ведение счёта',
            type: 'checkbox',
            id: 6,
          },
          {
            item: 'Открытие счёта',
            type: 'checkbox',
            id: 7,
          },
          {
            item: 'Закрытие счёта',
            type: 'checkbox',
            id: 8,
          },
          {
            item: 'Платежи и переводы',
            type: 'checkbox',
            id: 9,
          },
          {
            item: 'Кассовые операции',
            type: 'checkbox',
            id: 10,
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        item: 'Кредиты и гарантии',
        type: 'checkbox',
        id: 11,
        children: [
          {
            item: 'Кредиты в целом',
            type: 'checkbox',
            id: 12,
          },
          {
            item: 'Экспресс кредитование',
            type: 'checkbox',
            id: 13,
          },
          {
            item: 'Овердрафт',
            type: 'checkbox',
            id: 14,
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        item: 'Бизнес-портал',
        type: 'checkbox',
        id: 15,
      },
      {
        item: 'Офисы',
        type: 'checkbox',
        id: 16,
      },
      {
        item: 'Банкоматы',
        type: 'checkbox',
        id: 17,
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    item: 'Отзывы',
    type: 'checkbox',
    id: 18,
    children: [
      {
        item: 'Негативные',
        type: 'checkbox',
        id: 19,
      },
      {
        item: 'Оценка',
        type: 'slider',
        id: 20,
        slider: {
          from: 0,
          to: 10
        },
      },
    ],
  },
];

function existIds(data, ids) {
  return data.reduce((acum, item)=> {
    if (ids.includes(item.id)) {
      acum.push(item);
      return acum;
    }
    if (!item.children) return acum;
    const ch = existIds(item.children, ids);
    if (!ch.length) return acum;
    const newItem = Object.assign({}, item);
    newItem.children = ch;
    acum.push(newItem);
    return acum;
  }, []);
}

console.log(existIds(filters, [10, 20]));
```

Comment: подскажите, а мне надо ещё удалять из chidren'ов все элементы, которые не выделены, как это можно сделать?

Comment: @МихаилКамахин переписал чтоб фильтровать дочерние элементы

Comment: благодарю за короткое решение!